# Fail to form a binary classification and use predict_prob(): Random Forest, opencv

Tags: opencv, random, binary, classification

I used opencv to do random forest and I've built the forests successfully. But then I need to use predict_prob to know the exact chance that sample belongs to the second class.
I now how it works but there is an error saying my forest is not binary classification and I can't use predict_prob. How can I make my forest binary? I've tried many ways and searched everywhere but find no clue on this.

Here is my code

```
CvMat* data = 0;  
CvMat* responses = 0;  
CvMat* var_type = 0;  

//I skipped some lines

data=cvCreateMat(row_s,1024,CV_32FC1);
responses=cvCreateMat(row_s,1,CV_32FC1);

//load data and responses, responses consist of only 1 and 0

var_type = cvCreateMat( data->cols + 1, 1, CV_8U );  
cvSet( var_type, cvScalarAll(CV_VAR_ORDERED) );  
cvSetReal1D( var_type, data->cols, CV_VAR_CATEGORICAL ); 

CvRTrees forest;
forest.train(data,  CV_ROW_SAMPLE, responses, 0, 0, var_type, 0, 
CvRTParams( 5, 20, 0, false, 2, 0, false, 100, 10, 0, CV_TERMCRIT_ITER ));
```

and after this, I can use predict() correctly but I can't use predict_prob()

Answer (score 0):

Which version of opencv are u using? 
I am doing the same thing with version 2.4.3. The only major difference I see between what we are doing is that I am using c++ style code. 
Here is my code, this works for me.

```
void train(){
    cv::Mat types(numberOfClassifierDimensions + 1, 1, CV_8UC1);
    types.setTo(cv::Scalar(CV_VAR_NUMERICAL));
    types.at<char>(numberOfClassifierDimensions, 0) = CV_VAR_CATEGORICAL;

    cv::Mat dataset(0, numberOfClassifierDimensions, CV_32FC1);
    cv::Mat classes(0, 1, CV_8UC1);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < featureWeightsPositive.rows ; ++i){
        dataset.push_back(featureWeightsPositive.row(i));
        classes.push_back(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i < featureWeightsNegative.rows; ++i){
        dataset.push_back(featureWeightsNegative.row(i));
        classes.push_back(0);
    }

    classifier.train(dataset, classes, types);
}

//the classifier.train() function
void train(cv::Mat trainingData, cv::Mat classifications, cv::Mat varType){

    std::vector<float> priorsVect(numberOfClasses, 1);
    float* priors = &priorsVect[0];


        // define the parameters for training the random forest (trees)
        CvRTParams params = CvRTParams(25, 5, 0, false, 15, priors, false, 4, 100, 0.01f, CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS );

        // train random forest classifier (using training data)
        rtree->train(trainingData, CV_ROW_SAMPLE, classifications,
                     cv::Mat(), cv::Mat(), varType, cv::Mat(), params);

}
```

After this initialisation I can just call:

```
rtree->predict_prob(sample);
```

Hope this helps you